# Best way to fuzzy match values in a data frame and then replace the value?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a dataframe containing various datapoints of customer data. I'm looking to essentially replace any junk phone numbers as a blank value, right now I'm struggling to find an efficient way to find potential junk values such as a phone number like 111-111-1111 and replace that specific value with a blank entry.

I currently have a fairly ugly solution where I'm going through 3 fields; home phone, cell phone and work phone, locating the index values of the rows in question and respective column and then am replacing those,

with regards to actually finding junk values in a dataframe, is there a better approach to this than what I am currently doing?

```
row_index = dataset[dataset['phone'].str.contains('11111')].index
column_index = dataset.columns.get_loc('phone')
```

Afterwards, I would zip these up and cycle through a for loop, using dataset.iat[row_index, column_index] = ''. The row and column index variables would also have the junk values in the 'cellphone' and 'workphone' columns appended on as well.

Comment: It doesn't help with actually finding the junk values, but here's a simpler way of replacing them: `dataset.loc[dataset["phone"].map(is_junk), "phone"] = ""`.

Comment: I will give this a shot! Any idea why I get the following error though? Here is how I've implemented it. dataset.loc[dataset["phone"].astype(str).map('1111111111'), "phone"] = "" however it is returning  TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Take a look at the docs for `map()`, I think that’s the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas 'where' function tends to be quick:

```
dataset['phone'] = dataset['phone'].where(~dataset['phone'].str.contains('11111'),
                                         None)
```